# Diff branches on GitHub without downloading them and create an alert system for changes

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-diff

I am using `git diff --no-index --name-status https://<remote-url>/compare/branch1...branch2`

But unable to get a difference it says :
`usage : git diff --no-index [<options>] <path> <path>`

Is there a better way to diff between two remote branches of git without downloading locally. Can anyone help with some references?

Comment: Git, on the command line, does not do that. *GitHub* (which is a *web hosting site*, not a command) can compare two commits, but you do that with a web browser, not with the `git` command on the command line.

Comment: @torek though the GitHub REST API sort of turns it into a command ;) see my answer.

Comment: Akhil, I took the time to research an answer for you. You should at least respond with feedback if my answer was not acceptable.

Comment: Hi Inigo, I wasn't active for a while, thank you for the prompt answer. The GitHub Rest API is good and the information you gave really helped. But it was becoming rather complex to incorporate it. So I am currently continuing with old method of - git clone or pull and thereafter a git diff between branches from the downloaded repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest), either via one of the [libraries](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/libraries) or directly via the REST API.

The REST API includes a [Compare two commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits) request. Here's an excerpt from the docs:

> The `basehead` param is comprised of two parts: `base` and `head`. Both must be branch names in `repo`. To compare branches across other repositories in the same network as `repo`, use the format `<USERNAME>:branch`.
>
> The response from the API is equivalent to running the `git log base..head` command; however, commits are returned in chronological order. Pass the appropriate media type to fetch diff and patch formats.